# Multithread JavaScript: Image Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, multithreading

I want to make a simple slider for my webpage. Below is the function to load images.

However, it's not running as expected. It's an infinite loop and freeze the webpage. I'm not sure how to fix this but I think that it has to be run on another thread.

What is the best solution for this? Thank you.

```
function loadProd_logos() {
    var prod_logos = ["prod_01.png", "prod_02.png"];
    var prod_cnt = prod_logos.length;
    var prod_last = prod_cnt - 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < prod_cnt; i++) {
        prod_logos[i] = '<img class="prod_logo" src="prod_thumb/' + prod_logos[i] + '">';
    }

    var x = 0;
    while (1 == 1) {
        var html = prod_logos[x];
        $(".prod_logo").slideUp("slow");
        wait(1000);
        $(".product_thumb").empty();
        $(".product_thumb").append(html);
        $(".prod_logo").slideDown("slow");
        wait(5000);
        x++;
        if(x == prod_last) {
            x = 0;
        }
    }

}

function wait(x) {
    setTimeout(function () {
    }, x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One immediate problem that I see is that `wait` is assumed to be a blocking function. `setTimeout` works by firing the provided callback after x milliseconds. If you want to perform a task repeatedly over an interval, use `setInterval` and perform the operation within the callback you provide.

https://jsfiddle.net/kd4x3uw5/